# Why Won't My HTML Recognize My Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to learn Angular JS. I have written this small piece of code, but for some reason I cannot get the HTML to recognize the Angular.JS.

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="store">
   <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div ng-controller = "storeController as store">
           <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
       </div>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "angular-1.2.29/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src= "app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.JS file:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('store', [ ]); 
app.controller('StoreController', function() {
    this.product = item;
});
var item = {
    name: 'stuff',
    price: 2.44,
    description: 'lame',
}
})();
```

My output is {{store.product.name}}, instead of the 'stuff' that i'm expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise to try and match the case:

```
<div ng-controller = "StoreController as store">
```

Capital S.

Comment: That did it!, thanks. I've checked this thing 100 times, I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Haha this happens to me all the time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Fix that line

```
 <div ng-controller = "storeController as store">
```

to

```
 <div ng-controller="StoreController">
```

['Controller as syntax' is a good thing](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), but in your case you named app with the same name.

And made a typo in 's' instead 'S' as @Idos noticed